# How can I make a new page for each post that I make with fopen?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm creating a PHP news portal. How can I automatically create a new page (with header and footer) for each post that I make?

I am trying to do that with fopen/fclose, but I do not know how to get the post's id from the database(MySQL) and make it show on the URL. Here's how it is now:

```
<?php

    $myFile = "new_article.php";   
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("error");  
    $stringData = '

    <?php include "header.php";?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>test</title></head>


    </html>

    <?php include "footer.php";?>

    ';  
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: You need to read up on how to make an SQL query, and how to utilize the results within PHP.  You're not asking a specific question, you're asking for help in writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Auto prepend and auto append in PHP. You can set these in a variety of ways, including in htaccess, php.ini, etc., depending on your php configuration

see php.net docs or https://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess for an example with .htaccess